# Unknown report type: webkit Error when printing report?

Tags: webkit, report, odoo

I been with the following error for the past few days and I can't get a clue how to proceed.

The full error is:

```
2015-01-26 17:29:25,162 21218 ERROR myodoo openerp.service.report: Exception: Unknown report type: webkit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/report.py", line 93, in go
    result, format = openerp.report.render_report(cr, uid, ids, object, datas, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/report/__init__.py", line 40, in render_report
    return registry['ir.actions.report.xml'].render_report(cr, uid, ids, name, data, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 155, in render_report
    return new_report.create(cr, uid, res_ids, data, context)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 391, in create
    raise NotImplementedError(_('Unknown report type: %s') % report_type)
NotImplementedError: Unknown report type: webkit

2015-01-26 17:29:25,397 21218 ERROR myodoo openerp.addons.web.controllers.main: An exception occured during an http request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 69, in wrap
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1576, in index
    request.session.db, request.session.uid, request.session.password, report_id)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 807, in proxy_method
    result = dispatch_rpc(self.service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 100, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/report.py", line 34, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/report.py", line 141, in exp_report_get
    return _check_report(report_id)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/report.py", line 119, in _check_report
    raise openerp.osv.orm.except_orm(exc.message, exc.traceback)
except_orm: (u'Unknown report type: webkit', (<type 'exceptions.NotImplementedError'>, NotImplementedError(u'Unknown report type: webkit',), <traceback object at 0x7fa2f9af8dd0>))
```

I been developing on my module so I thought it was something I touched, but even when I install previous working versions of the module I still get the same error.

That makes me feel that there might be a change in the system but I checked if **wkhtmltopdf** is working and everything seems normal.

Any clue on where to look will be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you don't have the Webkit report engine installed.
Check if the `report_webkit` module is installed.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Yes I have "Webkit Report Engine" Installed

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to find, the error seems vague as all webkit modules are there.